# "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Unexpected internal error." from cache.add operation in service worker

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, browser-cache, offline

We have a number of websites where during first page load, the SW calls `caches.add` for multiple (>200) files. For one of these websites, some of our users semi-consistently (1/10 times) see the above error in their console, which always happens during a `caches.add(request)` call (which rejects with this error message). The network request made by the failing caches.add() call always succeeds.

I'm really just trying to understand what this error message is telling me and how I can debug this problem further. I know it's not an issue with the storage quota (the users all have more than enough), but this error doesn't appear to be a common Chrome one and I'm struggling on where to look next.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRM3i.png)

Comment: I never found a solution to this problem, it's nearly definitely a local problem with the users version of Chrome (it works perfectly in incognito mode, or with a guest profile) but what exactly causes this problem I don't know

Comment: Seeing the same errors with some Chrome devices, also getting some `Entry already exists.` errors

Comment: Getting this error on chrome on ubuntu with whatsapp web. Deleted all the whatsapp cookies and it went away and whatsapp web was able to load.